# Disable Unnecessary escape character: \/ no-useless-escape

Tags: regex, reactjs, eslint

I have this regex of mine that will check the string if it contains link or url `(i.e. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-escape)`. Using this regex `/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig`, I've encountered and error while running my test cases in react about `Unnecessary escape character: \/                    no-useless-escape`. How to disable this eslint-error in order for me to proceed with my test case and use the regex.

Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's the `\/` in `[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]` and `[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]` (NOT the ones in `:\/\/`). Most characters do not have to be escaped within a character class (square brackets). This should be equivalent: `/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|])/ig`
See https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html for more info, but the relevant part:

> In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters
> inside a character class are the closing bracket ], the backslash ,
> the caret ^, and the hyphen -. The usual metacharacters are normal
> characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by
> a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use [+*]. Your regex will
> work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character
> class, but doing so significantly reduces readability.

Comment: How can I disable it?

Comment: If you're using `create-react-app`, you probably can't without ejecting, but it's a valid warning, so easiest way to "disable" it is to fix it. ;-)

Comment: For the record you actually *can* override these in React using the special ESLint comments in Abhinav Kinagi's answer.

Comment: But if I paste `[:.,/]` into https://regex101.com/ it says there's a pattern error - "An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\\)" Shouldn't this be okay?

Comment: @evolross On the left, there is a selector for which regex implementation to use. Looks like that error is only reported for the 2 PHP flavors, not the others. Unfortunately, there is no single standard between implementations, so there will be some variances between implementations. There are a lot more similarities than differences, so it's a lot more portable than e.g. programming language syntax. Still, if using a tool like that site, it's generally best to select one that uses the engine from the language you're using.

Answer (score 97):

You can use [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) and try adding either of the things:-

1. `//eslint-disable-line` on the line to disable warnings.
2. `//eslint-disable-next-line` to line before to disable warnings.

See from docs of ESLint, [Disabling Rules with Inline Comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments).

> To disable all rules on a specific line, use a line or block comment in one of the following formats:
>
> ```
> alert('foo'); // eslint-disable-line
>
> // eslint-disable-next-line
> alert('foo');
>
> /* eslint-disable-next-line */
> alert('foo');
>
> alert('foo'); /* eslint-disable-line */
> ```

---

You can disable warnings in entire file by adding `/* eslint-disable */` at the top of the file.

> To disable rule warnings in an entire file, put a `/* eslint-disable */` block comment at the top of the file:
>
> ```
> /* eslint-disable */
>    alert('foo');
> ```

Answer (score 25):

You can also use

```
/* eslint-disable no-useless-escape */
```

to disable rule for entire script file.

Answer (score 12):

```
//eslint-disable-next-line
```

place this above the line of code

OR

```
/*eslint no-undef: 0*/
```

place this on the first line of the file(or first line of the script tag)
this would make eslint disabled on the whole file

Answer (score 4):

`\` gives error from below code in my `NodeJS typescript` project, code editor is VS Code -

Code -

```
if (!(/^[\-0-9a-zA-Z\.\+_]+@[\-0-9a-zA-Z\.\+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/).test(String(req.body.email))) { ... }
```

Error -

```
Unnecessary escape character: \+. (eslintno-useless-escape)
```

Solution -

```
//eslint-disable-next-line
```

Final code -

```
//eslint-disable-next-line
if (!(/^[\-0-9a-zA-Z\.\+_]+@[\-0-9a-zA-Z\.\+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/).test(String(req.body.email))) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the following code snippet for validating an email address:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*@[a-z]*[\.a-z]*/.test(value)
```

The linter was showing an error due to '\.' inside square brackets ('[]'). Square brackets do not need an escape character ('\') to make use of '.'. I removed the '\'  inside '[]' (as shown below) and the error got resolved.

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9.]*@[a-z]*[.a-z]*/.test(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just have to remove the

> \

from my regx and here how it looked before

```
/^\w+\-/g;
```

after

```
/^\w+-/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the correct answers above, if you want to completely disable the rule for your project entirely, you can add the line `'no-useless-escape': 0,` in your `.eslintrc.js` under the `rules` property

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar warning in react.

> `Unnecessary escape character: \# no-useless-escape`

Simply just remove whatever is mentioned in the warning. In my case, I had `\#` in the warning, so I just removed it from the line which was mentioned in the warning.