# How to fix this regex to remove JSLint Unnecessary escape warning?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, jslint

I'm getting a url then stripping the domain with an `onClick` handler in `React` using a regEx like this :

```
const path = e.target.closest('a');
if (!path) return;
e.preventDefault();

console.log('path: ', path.href.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, ''));
```

So if the url was say `http://example.com/my-super-funky-page`, it will correctly `console.log` everything after `http://example.com` - eg :

```
/my-super-funky-page
```

But I seem to have an issue with the regEx containing a useless escape. JS Lint reports :

```
Unnecessary escape character: \/  no-useless-escape
```

What do I need to remove to still make this work as expected. I tried a few things and it broke the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/^.*\/\/[^/]+/
```

The `/` in the character class doesn't need escaping

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want to be notified about unnecessary escapes, you can safely disable this rule.

This will work:
`^.*\/\/[^/]+`

> In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters
>   inside a character class are the closing bracket ], the backslash \,
>   the caret ^, and the hyphen -. The usual metacharacters are normal
>   characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by
>   a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use [+*]. Your regex will
>   work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character
>   class, but doing so significantly reduces readability.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277133/disable-unnecessary-escape-character-no-useless-escape)